# Отправка видео через telebot

Tags: python, telegram, бот, telebot

Мне надо отправить видео через библиотеку `telebot`:

```py
@client.message_handler(content_types = ['text', 'video'])
def get_text(message):
    if message.text == 'Заказ выплаты':
        client.send_message(message.chat.id, '.....')
    **elif message.text == 'Пополнение баланса':
        video = open('ABOBA.mp4', 'rb')
        client.send_video(message.chat.id, 'video')**
    elif message.text == 'О UnitTrust':
        client.send_message(message.chat.id, '.....')
    elif message.text == 'Связь с поддержкой':
        client.send_message(message.chat.id, '.....')
```

Но видео почему то не отправляется.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ты вместо файла в переменной `video` шлёшь строку `'video'`. Попробуй убрать кавычки. Вот так:

```py
client.send_video(message.chat.id, video)
```

[Пример из документации:](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI#telebot)

```py
# sendVideo
video = open('/tmp/video.mp4', 'rb')
tb.send_video(chat_id, video)
```

Comment: Если хотите отправить видеосообщение (круглое которое), то нужно использовать метод `client.send_video_note(chat_id, video)`.

Comment: спасибо, не заметил я эту ошибку

Comment: Отметьте, пожалуйста, ответ как верный, если он Вам помог.